# How to start a new line for long strings represented by their references?

Tags: python, python-3.x

starting a new line for long strings

```
line1 = "abc"
line2 = "gfd"
string = (line1)\n(line2)\n
print(string)
```

I am expecting to get a result like this in Python3:

```
abc
gfd
```

but it gives me: `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: I am expecting to get a result like: abc\ngdf   where gdf start in a new line

Answer (score 0):

You can use triple quotes to quote a literal string of multiple lines:

```
string = '''abc
gfd'''
```

Or if you would like to join multiple one-line string variables into a multi-line string, you can use the `str.join` method:

```
string = '\n'.join((line1, line2))
```

Comment: Thank you! I found this method is really useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just get "abc gfd" from those two strings you can just add the strings.

```
string = line1 + " " + line2
```

or

```
string = line1 + "\n" + line2
```

for a new line in-between the strings.